# Send access_token to Header?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am not able to send access_token to the header.I have login system ,which generates the access_token after successful login.Then i have to send access_token to the header.I am getting Unexpected response code 404.How can this issue be solved?

SessionManagement

```
public class SessionManagement {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    public static final String KEY_access_token = "access_token";
    public static final String KEY_token_type = "token_type";
    public static final String Key_EXPIRES_IN = "expires_in";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "userName";
    public static final String KEY_MASTER_ID = "MasterID";
    public static final String KEY_Name = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_Access = "Access";
    public static final String KEY_Issued = ".issued";
    public static final String KEY_expires = ".expires";
    String user_new_access_token;

    // Constructor
    public SessionManagement(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }


    public void createLoginSession(String accesstoken, String tokentype, String expiresin, String username, String masterId, String name, String access, String issued, String expires) {

        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(KEY_access_token, accesstoken);
        editor.putString(KEY_token_type, tokentype);
        editor.putString(Key_EXPIRES_IN, expiresin);
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        editor.putString(KEY_MASTER_ID, masterId);
        editor.putString(KEY_Name, name);
        editor.putString(KEY_Access, access);
        editor.putString(KEY_Issued, issued);
        editor.putString(KEY_expires, expires);
        editor.apply();

        String user_new_access_token = pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null);
        String user_new_access_tokentype = pref.getString(KEY_token_type, null);
        String user_name_expiresin = pref.getString(Key_EXPIRES_IN, null);
        String user_name_Username = pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null);
        String user_name_masterID = pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID, null);
        String user_name_name = pref.getString(KEY_Name, null);
        String user_name_access = pref.getString(KEY_Access, null);
        String user_name_issued = pref.getString(KEY_Issued, null);
        String user_name_expires = pref.getString(KEY_expires, null);


        Log.d("TAG", "Access Token :" + accesstoken + user_new_access_token);
        Log.d("TAG", "TokenType:" + user_new_access_tokentype);
        Log.d("TAG", "Expires in:" + user_name_expiresin);
        Log.d("TAG", "UserName:" + user_name_Username);
        Log.d("TAG", "MasterID:" + user_name_masterID);

        Log.d("TAG", "Name:" + user_name_name);
        Log.d("TAG", "Access:" + user_name_access);
        Log.d("TAG", "Issued:" + user_name_issued);
        Log.d("TAG", "Expires:" + user_name_expires);


        //  String user_name_new = pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null);

        //  Log.d("TAG", " :" + accesstoken + " user_name_new:" + user_name_new);


        //  Log.d(tokentype, "admin");
        //ad Log.d(expiresin, "expiresin");

        editor.commit();


    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     */
    public void checkLogin() {
        // Check login status
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Get stored session data
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        //  user.put(KEY_USERNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null));
        user.put(KEY_access_token, pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null));
        user.put(KEY_token_type, pref.getString(KEY_token_type, null));
        //  user.put(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, pref.getString(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, null));
        // user.put(KEY_MASTER_ID, pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID, null));
        // user.put(KEY_access_token, pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null));
        // user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        //user.put(KEY_Access, pref.getString(KEY_Access, null));


        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     */
    public void logoutUser() {

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


    public String getMasterId() {
        String masterID = pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID, null);
        return masterID;
    }

    public String getAccess() {
        String accessID = pref.getString(KEY_Access, null);
        return accessID;
    }





    public String getAccesstToken()
    {
        String user_new_access_token = pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null);
        return user_new_access_token;
    }







    public void clear() {
        Log.d("TAg", "Full Cleared");
        editor.clear();

        // editor.remove(KEY_MASTER_ID);
        // editor.remove(KEY_USERNAME);
        editor.commit();


    }





    /**
     * Quick check for login
     **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }

}
```

Home class

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    LinearLayout calendar, classSchedule, progressReport, profile, fee, dshboard, setting, logout, attendance;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public static final String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/student/";
    ImageView studentprofileimage;
    TextView profilename, sprofilename;
    String master_id, access_token, accessID;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        studentprofileimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar);//initilise student name
        profilename = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profilename);// student profile name
        sprofilename = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.student_profilename);


        dshboard = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_layout);
        calendar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.calender_layout);
        fee = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_fee);
        classSchedule = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.class_schedule);
        progressReport = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_report);
        profile = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_profile);
        setting = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainsetting);
        logout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlogout);
        attendance = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.class_attendance);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        calendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        classSchedule.setOnClickListener(this);
        fee.setOnClickListener(this);
        dshboard.setOnClickListener(this);
        progressReport.setOnClickListener(this);
        profile.setOnClickListener(this);
        setting.setOnClickListener(this);
        logout.setOnClickListener(this);
        attendance.setOnClickListener(this);
        FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tx.replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard());
        tx.commit();

        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(Home.this);
        session.checkLogin();
        master_id = session.getMasterId();
        Log.d("TAG", "master_id:" + master_id);
        access_token = session.getAccesstToken();
        Log.d("TAG", "access token" + access_token);
        accessID = session.getAccess();
        Log.d("TAG", "access:" + accessID);
        makeJsonObjectRequest();


    }

    StudentInformation studentInformation;

    public void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        final String URL = Navigation_URL;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            studentInformation = new StudentInformation();
                            studentInformation.StdID = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("StdID"));
                            studentInformation.Name = jsonObject.getString("NAME");
                            studentInformation.Gender = (String) jsonObject.get("GENDER");
                            studentInformation.Phonenumber = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("PHONENO"));
                            studentInformation.StudentClass = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("CLASS"));
                            studentInformation.Enrolled_Year = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("ENROLLEDYEAR"));
                            studentInformation.Address = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("ADDRESS"));
                            studentInformation.DOB = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("DOB"));
                            studentInformation.Nationality = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("NATIONALITY"));
                            profilename.setText(studentInformation.Name);
                            studentInformation.Photo = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("Photo"));
                            studentInformation.CatID = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("Cat_ID"));
                            studentInformation.base64 = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("base64"));
                            studentInformation.Marks = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("Marks"));


                            JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("studentDetails");
                            studentInformation.GuardianStudentId = studentDetails_obj.getString("StdID");
                            studentInformation.Guardianphonenumber = studentDetails_obj.getString("GUARDIAN_PHONE_NO");
                            studentInformation.Guardianmobilenumber = studentDetails_obj.getString("MOBILE_NO");
                            studentInformation.Guardianfirstname = studentDetails_obj.getString("First_NAME");
                            studentInformation.GuardianLastName = studentDetails_obj.getString("Last_Name");
                            studentInformation.GuardianRelation = studentDetails_obj.getString("Relation");
                            studentInformation.GuardianDOB = studentDetails_obj.getString("DOB");
                            studentInformation.GuardianEducation = studentDetails_obj.getString("Education");
                            studentInformation.GuardianOccupation = studentDetails_obj.getString("Occupation");
                            studentInformation.GuardianIncome = studentDetails_obj.getString("Income");
                            studentInformation.GuardianEmail = studentDetails_obj.getString("Email");
                            studentInformation.GuardianAddLine1 = studentDetails_obj.getString("AddLine1");
                            studentInformation.GuardianAddLine2 = studentDetails_obj.getString("AddLine2");
                            studentInformation.GuardianState = studentDetails_obj.getString("State");
                            studentInformation.GuardianCountry = studentDetails_obj.getString("Country");


                            JSONObject studentDetails_obj1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("stdCategory");
                            studentInformation.Category = studentDetails_obj1.getString("Category");
                            studentInformation.CategoryId = studentDetails_obj1.getString("Cat_ID");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //  Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Why this error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("id", master_id);
                map.put("accessID", accessID);
                map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                return map;

            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int id = v.getId();


        if (id == R.id.dashboard_layout) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        } else if (id == R.id.calender_layout) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new CalenderFragment())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.view_fee) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Fee())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        } else if (id == R.id.class_schedule) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentClassSchedule())
                    .commit();


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.progress_report) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ProgressFragment())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.class_attendance) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new AttendanceStudentFragment())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.view_profile) {

            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
            bundle1.putSerializable("student_obj", studentInformation);

            Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle1);
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.mainsetting) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new SettingFragment())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.mainlogout) {

            SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(Home.this);
            session.clear();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        }


    }


}
```

[image]

I am getting  Unexpected response code 404.How to resolve this?

Comment: i believe it could be, put the following line in your getHeaders function.      headers.put("access_token", "stringoftoken");

Comment: its not working.Check updated code